# Git add is ignoring certain files even when .gitignore does not exist

Tags: gitignore, git-add

I am facing a rather strange issue with my git working folders. Here's the summary:

- I previously had a local git repo with a .gitignore file that ignored certain files/folders.
- I deleted the repo (.git folder) and also the .gitignore file
- Then I initialized a new one with git init in the same folder. Now when I do a "git add .", the previous ignore pattern is retained for some reason.
- Even stranger,this happens with any new project following the same folder structure no matter where I place the project on my computer.
- I tried deleting and recreating the files multiple times. I even created a new .gitignore file with a different pattern. It does not seem to have an effect except when it is set to ignore everything (with just * in the file)

My guess is that the .gitignore pattern I deleted is somewhere saved that I dont know the location of. If anyone has faced a similar issue or know what I could be missing, I'd love to know. 
I am still new to git. Sorry if this is something very obvious that I have missed out on.

UPDATE:
I still have not found the reason for this behaviour but managed to reset everything by doing 'git add --force .' in the directory and then deleting the repo. Now I initialized a new repo that works as expected.

Comment: What is the output of `git config --global core.excludesfile`?

Comment: It turns up empty:

poh@nb-poh MINGW64 /c/CM_Projects/Internal/HPC_main (master) 
$ git config --global core.excludesfile 


poh@nb-poh MINGW64 /c/CM_Projects/Internal/HPC_main (master) 
$

Comment: How are you deleting the older folder?

Comment: @qaisjp I am just deleting it with right-click -> delete. What I dont understand is how the ignore pattern turns up on a completely unrelated new folder structure.

Comment: Make sure you have `cd`'d to the correct folder in your terminal after you delete it. If you don't, your terminal will still be in the old folder (in the trash)

Comment: That's good to know. Although I opened a new terminal altogether in the new location